# How azure will cost when working with different regions

Tags: azure

I have Exe application which will be used by **customer application (webrole-Region A)** as startup task to send data to database through one **REST service (webrole-Region B)**.

Now if Customer app and REST service are both belongs to different regions then will azure cost? and if yes then how much it would cost to sending data?

Is it reliable to set up REST services in all regions and put some check in EXE(startup task) to get region in which customer app belongs and assign specific REST service URI by region?

Please give me suggestion if i understood something wrong!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, if I understand your problem correctly, you have a Web role consuming compute time in Region A and another Service talking to a database in Region B, also consuming compute time.

if this is correct,
then you will pay for the compute hours (depending on the size of the VM chosen and number of instances running) in both regions.

you will also pay for the data leaving the Region A datacentre as per the Egress data charges

you will also pay for the database to exist in Region B, depending on the size of the database running, assuming it is SQL.

all current pricing for Windows Azure is available at : http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/advanced/

hope this helps answer your questions!

Answer (score 0):

Cost will be calculated based on $ irrespective of region. For Ingress Data movement into data center no charges will be incurred.Bandwidth consumed for data egress for the data going out of a data center. data ingress is free. If you want to reduce the price, please try to make use of Affinity Group feature in Windows Azure to reduce the price.

Please look into below url for pricing details in Windows Azure.
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/